# Are there any way to use a Parallel Stream with Realm?

Tags: android, parallel-processing, realm, java-stream

I am looking for a way to use parallel streams with a list of RealmResults. The problem is that Realm have a restriction to use RealmResults between threads.

This is the code that I would like to use:

```
RealmResults<RealmModel> entitiesDAO = query.findAll();

final ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

final List<In> entities = entitiesDAO.stream().parallel().map(entityDAO -> {
     final In entity =  modelMapper.map(entityDAO, typeIn);
     return entity;
}).collect(toList());

//This code works perfectly without parallel streams:
/*final List<In> entities = entitiesDAO.stream().map(entityDAO -> {
    final In entity =  modelMapper.map(entityDAO, typeIn);
    return entity;
}).collect(toList());*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to do it, you have to use frozen objects.

When you create your Realm object you have to do it like this:

```
final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance().freeze();
```

You can wath it in the Realm documentation: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/ in Freezing objects section.